# Firebase authentication not working when I use my website as a web app in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, web-applications, webview

I have a webpage that uses Firebase auth to register/login users. I decided to convert the webpage into an app by using Android Studio's webView feature. I've been able to load the web url but when i try to log in, it doesn't work. I don't think firebase auth is working here.

I'm a web dev and not an app developer but I'm following some online tutorials for converting websites to apps using WebView in Android Studio.

Is there any thing I need to add in order to make firebase work in web apps?

Android Studio Code (MainActivity.java):

```
package com.example.indianrobostore;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;
WebSettings webSettings;
private String webURL = "my website url";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(webURL);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
}
```

XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I went through a few articles and found I need to enable DOM Storage for this to work.

Code : `webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);`